# tcl error when removing/adding pictures to folder in a slide show, python, tkinter, itertools, cycle

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am having some trouble with an small slide show script that I am trying to make. The script runs just fine when the folder of files is not altered, but if i add a picture to the folder I get an tcl error stating that the file cannot be opened or is missing. I am really struggeling to see the issue here and I am hoping that some of you can?

the function where adding a picture to the folder without having to restart it is the main function, so that the slides just change automatically. It will be a slide show of graphs running in our office as an information screen.

See the code and error underneath. Any help is much appritiated!

**Code**

```
from itertools import cycle
import os

try:
    import Tkinter as tk
except ImportError:


class App(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self,x, y, delay):
        print "init running"
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.geometry('+{}+{}'.format(x, y))
        self.delay = delay
        self.image_files = []
        self.new_image = []
        for path, subdirs, files in os.walk('C:\kitfinder2\pictures'):
            for filename in files:
                f = filename
                self.image_files.append(f)
                self.new_image.append(f)                
        self.pictures = cycle((tk.PhotoImage(file=image), image)
                              for image in self.image_files)
        self.picture_display = tk.Label(self)
        self.picture_display.pack()

    def UpdateImages(self):
        self.new_image = []
        for path, subdirs, files in os.walk('C:\kitfinder2\pictures'):
            for filename in files:
                f = filename
                self.new_image.append(f)            

        if len(self.image_files) != len(self.new_image):
            print "Difference!"
            self.image_files = []
            for path, subdirs, files in os.walk('C:\kitfinder2\pictures'):
                for filename in files:
                    f = filename
                    self.image_files.append(f)
            self.pictures = cycle((tk.PhotoImage(file=image), image)
                              for image in self.image_files)            

            print "image updated!:" + str(self.image_files)             
        self.show_slides()      
    def show_slides(self):  
        print self.image_files
        '''cycle through the images and show them'''
        img_object, img_name = next(self.pictures)
        self.picture_display.config(image=img_object)
        self.title(img_name)
        self.after(self.delay, self.UpdateImages)
    def run(self):
        self.mainloop()

delay = 3500




x = 100
y = 50
app = App( x, y, delay)
app.UpdateImages()
app.run()
```

**Error message**

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1486, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 533, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "start_stopp.py", line 56, in UpdateImages
    self.show_slides()
  File "start_stopp.py", line 60, in show_slides
    img_object, img_name = next(self.pictures)
  File "start_stopp.py", line 53, in <genexpr>
    for image in self.image_files)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 3326, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 3282, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
TclError: couldn't open "2.gif": no such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

You're only appending the basename and then trying to open it.  e.g. `2.gif`.  Unfortunately, `2.gif` isn't in the current directory -- it's (somewhere) in `'C:\kitfinder2\pictures'`

You probably want something like:

```
self.image_files.append(os.path.join(path, filename))
```

rather than simply:

```
self.image_files.append(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

Brother you can use:

photo = PhotoImage(file = "path_of_file")
you can put litter r before "path_of_file" to override putting douple \

photo = PhotoImage(file=r'F:\Python Programs\Tkinter\2.png')